# How do I turn off my HDMI monitor?

Tags: x11, xfce, monitors

I tried `xrandr --output 'HDMI-A-1' --off` which puts the screen as black for only a few seconds and doesn't turn anything off. `xset -display :0.0 dpms force off` does the same except it shows me the lock screen afterwards

The only time I ever seen linux turn off my screen is when I boot up my PC and not log in

Comment: what do you mean by `turn off`?

Comment: I have never seen an operating system actually turn off a screen. The OS just stops using it (turns it black) and then the screen itself may turn off after a while automatically. The question is why your `xrandr` command is being undone and what undoes it. What operating system is this? You mentioned Linux, but which one? And what graphical environment? Is this X or wayland?

Answer (score 3):

If you have multiple displays and wish to turn one of them off, you should use [Xfce's display settings dialog](https://docs.xfce.org/xfce/xfce4-settings/display) for that.

If you use the `xrandr` command while Xfce is also controlling the display settings, Xfce might promptly restore the state configured for it, overriding your `xrandr` command - which would match what seems to be happening to you.

If you have just one display, turning it off with `xrandr` would leave the X11 server  (and your GUI session) with no functional screens, and it won't like that at all. It will re-detect screens, "find" your screen again and effectively override your command.

To enable the screensaver, you should rather use [`xfce4-screensaver-command --activate`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/impish/man1/xfce4-screensaver-command.1.html) or similar. Typically, this first just turns the screen black, then (optionally) enables a DPMS power-save mode after a configurable number of minutes.

Since letting the screen power down completely makes it slower to power up again than just making the screen black, there is usually a delay of a minute or two after the screensaver starts before a power-save mode kicks in. That enables a faster response if you are e.g. presenting a document and the screensaver accidentally kicks in while you are talking.

(Actual presentation applications usually override the screensaver when in "presentation mode", but perhaps you're presenting something using a plain Web browser or some other program?)

Comment: `xfce4-screensaver-command --activate` had my screen go blank for about 12.5seconds (tried it twice timing with my phone) before going to the lock screen. I still have 0 idea what I can do but everything you said seems to make sense. I have 2 screens connected but I only have the one on. Only one seems to be detected

Comment: That's rather specific to xfce.